# getting error cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'paragraph' when compiling jrxml through java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, saxparseexception

When I was running report in ireport I got output correctly. But when I compile jrml file through java code I am getting error like

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 63; columnNumber: 38; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'paragraph'. No child element is expected at this point.

Here is my java code

```
    public   byte[] generate(String path,String fileName,String type,String query,HashMap<String,Object> param){
        byte[] output=null;

            Connection con=JdbcUtil.getJdbcConnection();
            JasperDesign jasperDesign=null;
            JasperReport jasperReport=null;
            System.out.println("Exec RT");
            try{

             jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(path+"\\"+fileName);
            }catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("t0:"+e1.getMessage());
            System.out.println("RTMap:"+param);
            try{           
            JRDesignQuery nQuery=new JRDesignQuery();
            nQuery.setText(query);
            jasperDesign.setQuery(nQuery);
                            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("t1:"+e.getMessage());}
            System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
            try{
                jasperReport =   JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path+"\\"+fileName);
            }catch(Exception e5){}
            JasperPrint jasperPrint=null;
            try{
             jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, con);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("RT0:"+e.getMessage());}
            String fName=fileName.substring(0,fileName.indexOf("."));

            JRExporter exporter= null;
            try{
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")){
                output=JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("html")){
                exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("rtf")){
                exporter=new JRRtfExporter();
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")){
                exporter  = new JRXlsExporter();
            }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("csv")){
                exporter=new JRCsvExporter();
            }
             output = exportReportToBytes(jasperPrint, exporter);
            }catch(Exception er){System.out.println("RT2:"+er.getMessage());
            } 
            }   
            return output;
    }
```

I have one sub report and one main report. I used ireport 4.0.2. 
My jrxml file (offerLetter.jrxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="offerLetter" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1417" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 6">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 6_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 6_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 6_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 7">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 7_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 7_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 7_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <parameter name="appid" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="logopath" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT  offer.INT_OFFERID,ecat.CHR_CATEGORYNAME,CONCAT(year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),CONCAT('-',year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)+1)) ayear,
DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%d-%b-%y'),
CONCAT( if(app.CHR_GENDER='Male','Mr. ', if(app.CHR_MARITALSTATUS ='M','Mrs.' ,'Ms.') ),' ',app.CHR_APPNAME) salute,office.CHR_OFFICENAME,desig.CHR_DESIGNAME,
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY) joining,
FUN_GET_takehome(hal.INT_APPID) takehome
FROM
 hrm_t_allowance hal,hrm_m_application app,hrm_t_offerletter offer,com_m_office office,com_m_desig desig,com_m_employeecategory ecat
 WHERE hal.INT_APPID=offer.INT_APPID AND app.INT_APPID=offer.INT_APPID AND offer.INT_DESIGID=desig.INT_DESIGID AND

offer.INT_OFFICEID=office.INT_OFFICEID AND hal.INT_APPID=$P{appid}
 AND ecat.INT_EMPLOYEECATEGORYID=offer.INT_CATEGORY;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="INT_OFFERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CHR_CATEGORYNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ayear" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,&apos;%d-%b-%y&apos;)" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="salute" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CHR_OFFICENAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CHR_DESIGNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="joining" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="takehome" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="84" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="171" y="-1" width="360" height="58"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{logopath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="218" y="57" width="128" height="27"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[OFFER LETTER]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="203" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="0" width="543" height="14"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["CARE/OFFER-"+$F{INT_OFFERID}+"/"+$F{CHR_CATEGORYNAME}+"/"+$F{ayear}+"."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="14" width="100" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%d-%b-%y')}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="12" y="38" width="57" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[To,]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="53" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{salute}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="68" width="206" height="13"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CHR_OFFICENAME}+","]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="98" width="543" height="14"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Dear."+$F{salute}+","]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="112" width="543" height="16"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["We are pleased to offer the post of  "+" \""+$F{CHR_DESIGNAME}+" \" "+" in our organisation at "+"\""+$F{CHR_OFFICENAME}+"\""+"."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="128" width="543" height="12"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["You are expected to join us on or before "+$F{joining}+" failing with this offer is not valid. Your salary details as mentioned bellow "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="12" y="140" width="41" height="38"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="appid">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{appid}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="logopath">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{logopath}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "offerLetter_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: it's 2023 and something similar is happening to me. there are no duplicate jasper jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result by deleting duplicated jasperreport jar files from the project